# char*, char[] and const char* - stack, code segment and compiler behavior

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

So I read somewhere, that declaring string like:

```
char * string="someString";
```

should not be used and instead we should use following:

```
const char* string = "someString";
```

I am not sure why is this a better approach, as I cannot change string declared in a second way.

Moreover I never experienced any problem, when I used simple:

```
char string[] = "someString";
```

and I used following, when I wanted string to be constant:

```
const char string[] = "someString";
```

So i wrote a simple program in order to see what is happening underhood:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* someString = "someString";
    char anotherString[] = "someString1";
    char* yetAnotherString = "someString2";
    const char yetyetAnotherString[] = "somestring3";

    printf("someString pointer = %p\n", someString);
    printf("anotherString = %p\n", anotherString);
    printf("yetAnotherString pointer = %p\n", yetAnotherString);
    printf("yetyetAnotherString = %p\n", yetyetAnotherString);

    return 0;
}
```

What I got was:

```
someString pointer = 000000013F2870B0
anotherString = 000000000017FD50
yetAnotherString pointer = 000000013F2870D0 //next to someString pointer
yetyetAnotherString = 000000000017FD60// next to anotherString
```

That would suggest that strings declared with pointers explicitly are in completely different memory space than ones declared with table syntax, although as we know tables are just normal pointers.

I searched a bit on the Internet about this and found out that the first and the third approach can allocate strings in a code segment, while others allocate it on the stack, that would explain why we should not declare strings with

```
char * string = "xyz";
```

As it will "allow" us to change data in code segment, which should not be allowed.

That's how far I managed to understand all these things but I cannot find answer on the following:

Why is the compiler allowed to allocate strings (in this case) in the code segment if I said explicitly that later on I want to be able to change value, where the pointer is pointing? Compiler should know this, so why is it doing it? How does compiler know what to do if I use table syntax if both in fact simply declare pointers?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha?rq=1 - in fact, it seems to be a duplicate because the first answer there seems to answer your questions, too.

Comment: this would also be interesting: `printf("&someString pointer = %p\n", &someString);`

Comment: Can you define what you mean with "table" in this context?

Comment: Putting `"someString"/"someString2"` is a different, potentially read-only,  memory space existed before C had the `const` keyword.